# Server Rendering: Prefetching data Performance

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, reactjs, redux

I have an React Redux server rendered application that runs well.

When I go on different page, I measured some server response time:

- On my **/singin** page, I got the response in 60ms. Good.
- On my **/user** page (require an authentication) I got the response in 300ms. because the server has to prefetch the current user session and the current user by asking an API to know if the user has access to this page
- On my **/user/graph** page. I got the response in 600ms. because the server has to prefetch the current user session, the current user and the graph data by asking an API.

The main issue is that I can't parallelize all these requests.

Here is the server flow:

- Receive page request for **/user/graph**
- Fetch **/api/user/session** and **/api/user/me** in parallel
- Do the route matching with React-Router (it needs to know if the user is authenticated or not to redirect him)
- At this point, the server knows the components that will be rendered. Foreach of them, it fetches the needed data in parallel. That means Fetch **/api/graph**, **/api/graphConstants1**, **/api/graphConstants2**, etc..
- React rendering

Here are my questions:

1. What is the best practice?
2. How could I decrease this initial rendering time due to prefetching requests?
3. Should I do big request (like **/api/graph**) only on the client? But what is the purpose of server rendering then?
4. Should I ask my api team to create a custom super method only for the rendering server to retrieve all data in one request?

Answer (score 0):

> > Here is the server flow:
> >
> > - Receive page request for `/user/graph`
> > - Fetch `/api/user/session` and `/api/user/me` in parallel
> > - Do the route matching with React-Router (it needs to know if the user is authenticated or not to redirect him)
> > - At this point, the server knows the components that will be rendered. Foreach of them, it fetches the needed data in parallel. That means Fetch `/api/graph`, `/api/graphConstants1`, `/api/graphConstants2`, etc..
> > - React rendering

This looks perfect to me, this is how a [Microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) based architecture should behave.

As stated by you, most of the API calls are being made in **parallel**, so there is not much to worry about the latency between successive API calls.

> > The main issue is that I can't parallelize all these request.

However, you could ask the API team to provide an umbrella API for the desired Microservices. In that scenario the API team needs to handle the processing in parallel or mutithreads.

> > Fetch `/api/user/session` and `/api/user/me` in parallel

Looks like, you are calling `/api/user/session` to validate the users' `session`. However, shouldn't you leverage `caching` for `/api/user/me`.

I guess `/api/user/me` this is a `GET` request, one approach to reduce this sort of calls. The `data` being sent by this API could easily be sent the `signin` API, if **signin** is successful and cache the data.

On any update to user data, i.e. on any `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` call, the exiting cached data can be purged, and the APIs, can return the latest state of the user which will be used to warm up the cache.

*PS: This sort of decision can/must not be made on a StackOverflow answer but needs in depth discussion and agreement between the API provider and consumer.*